# Running Eclipse Project built with Tomcat 7 on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

I'm working with a partner on a project and unfortunately, in his environment he's been using Tomcat 7 while the target environment needs to be Tomcat 6.

I'm trying to run the program in my Eclipse but I cannot launch it with tomcat 6.

I tried going into the Project Facets portion of properties, but I cannot make any changes.

Below is my Web.XML

```
<web-app xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <javaee:display-name>Run e-commerce site</javaee:display-name>
  <javaee:description> Run e-commerce site </javaee:description>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file> login.jsp </welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Title</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>BrowseByTitle</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Title</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/src/BrowseByTitle</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

The **Dynamic web module version** is not compatible. It may using **Dynamic web module version - 3.0**

You can create a new Dynamic web project and choose the **Dynamic web module version-2.5**. After this You can paste all your Java files  and web.xml in this project .
Try this, It will work for you.[image: You have to change here]

Comment: or You can change the **Dynamic web version** in your existing project by importing the project in Eclipse IDe and after this, right click on project and go to **properties**. In **properties click on Project Facets** and change the **Dynamic web version** to **2.5**.